# Have a button auto adjust & stay next to text regardless of text length

Tags: javascript, html, css

**How can I have a button automatically adjust and stay next to a word regardless of its length?** I am dealing with usernames.

For example, if i have a button alongside a username the length of `greg`:

*greg* |BUTTON|

I would like to have that button **automatically adjust** if a user were to sign up with a username the length of for example:

*williamson* |BUTTON|

*sam* |BUTTON|

*williamson_sam* |BUTTON|

How can i achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: use float:left in your css and use position absolute, display inline-block

Comment: Put the style of the button to display: inline-block; , no need to float anything if both the name and the button are inline.

Comment: _"would like to have that button automatically adjust"_ Adjust to what? To fill a specific container width? Can you include `html`, `css` tried at Question?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
p {
  float:left;
  margin: 0 5px
}
button {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<p>Williamson</p><button>Click Here</button>
<p>Bob</p><button>Click Here</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no snippet provided I tried to replicate the scenario. Hope this snippet will be useful

**HTML**

```
<input type= "text" id = "text">
<button id = "demoButton">Click</button>

<div>
<div id = "mySpan"></div>
<button type="button">DEMO BUTTON</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var _getDemoButton = document.getElementById("demoButton");
_getDemoButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = document.getElementById("text").value
})
```

CSS

```
#mySpan{
display:inline-block;
width:auto;
border:1px solid red;
}
```

The css part will be of your interest

Here is a [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/n65qdudk/) for demo